# Why are my faces warped?

Tags: modeling, faces

I'm having a weird issue with these faces.  In the first example, I used the boolean modifier to cut a hole, and as you can see the faces around the knob have this warped/sunken look:

[image]

In this second example, I extruded a face and the same result happened:

[image]

Does anyone know what's going on here?

[image]

Comment: The weird shading is due to the bad topology (you should change the edgeflows in some places and get rid of n-gons, otherwise the subsurf won't work properly). I'll try to help you with this. Meanwhile take a look at this http://topologyguides.com/

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Click on the mesh and go to vertex tab and click auto smooth

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...thanks it definitely straightens out the faces, but gets rid of the smoothness.  Even if I adjust the auto smooth angle it ends up distorting the mesh when it becomes smooth again.